# Hiding colors dropdown by selecting sizes in woocommerce product page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a WooCommerce website where I set variations for the product like sizes and colors.

Values for sizes used are Small|Medium|Large
Values for colors used are Pink|Blue|Yellow

Now, while adding to cart if I select small size then the color pink should be hidden as I don't have that combination .In the same way I have customer order notes field.
If I select Small Size then the custom order notes text field also need to hidden.

Can anyone tell me how to hide particular variations after selecting sizes from dropdown.

Added this code in theme/fucntion.php file butting getting error as:

Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var $aerialTr = jQuery('#pa_cream-quantity').closest('tr').hide();

jQuery('#pa_eggless').change(function($) {         
     selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();

    if(selectedValue  === 'half-kg') {
        $aerialTr.show();
    } else if (selectedValue === '1-kg') {
        $aerialTr.show();
    } else {
        $aerialTr.hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Any one can help me out these

Comment: dude, few days back a similar question was posted. It is becoming a common question now a days. But I am busy with another project. But in very near future I will work on a solution for this scenario.

Comment: @Alice this is the requirement and is urgent in my project so i ahve posted so that i may get any solutions from any one from this.

Comment: opps ! I don't think I will get time in next two days. But hope somebody else supports. Otherwise when I get time I will work on ... best of luck